# Which d3.js diagram should I use for custom line plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I have a line plot which represents evolution of communities (i.e., groups) of words over time. The presented plot has 10 timeslots; each timeslot represents one year period. Each black triangle represents one community and the circle around it refers to community size. Note that community could be born after the first timeslot (such communities are for example communities designated as New14 or New15). This constraint is the main reason why the [Sankey diagram](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey) is not appropriate for my task. Required functionality is also a tooltip behavior: when I go with cursor over a small triangle, the tooltip should list the words constitute that community.

I have two questions. First, which d3.js layout should be most relevant for my plot, and second, how should I organize my data. Any idea or suggestion is greatly welcome.

[image]